# Sorting multiple data frame columns with my own sorting function

Tags: r

So in my code I have some vectors, and then i create a data frame, which contains them:

```
n <- 10

a <- sample(0:9, n, replace=TRUE)

if (a %% 2 == 0){
  b <- sample(letters, n, replace = TRUE)
}
else{ 
  b <- sample(LETTERS, n, replace = TRUE)
}

ch <- append(LETTERS, letters)
c  <- sample(ch,  n, replace = TRUE)
d  <- sample(ch,  n, replace = TRUE)
e  <- sample(0:9, n, replace = TRUE)
f  <- sample(0:9, n, replace = TRUE)
g  <- sample(0:9, n, replace = TRUE)
h  <- "R"

ifelse((e+f+g) %% 3 == 0, 
       i <- sample("podz", n, replace = TRUE),
       i <- sample(paste("000", (e+f+g) %% 3, sep = ""), replace = TRUE))

df <- data.frame(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, i, i, i)
```

now, I tried to sort them by columns b,c and d. I found an answer here, probably the simplest one was following:

```
df[with(df, order(tolower(b),tolower(c),tolower(d))), ]
```

However, I found an insertion sort function that i tried to implement:

```
insertionsort_function <- function(A){
  for (j in 2:length(A)) {
    key = A[j] 
    i = j - 1 
    while (i > 0 && A[i] > key) {
      A[(i + 1)] = A[i]
      i = i - 1 
    }
    A[(i + 1)] = key
  }
  A
}
```

It works with vectors, but i am wondering, is there a way to sort this data frame with given 'insertionsort' function, the same way i did with regular 'order' function above? I want to compare a few things, and I tried a couple ways, and couldn't make it work. Or, eventually, maybe i should somehow put vectors into data structure other than data frame, and then try?

Comment: You want the insertion sort function to work on your data frame and sort by `b`, `c` and `d` at the same time?

Comment: Yes indeed, i want insertion sort function to do the same what      `df[with(df, order(tolower(b),tolower(c),tolower(d))), ]`  did.

Comment: Interessting problem. Perhaps that's a weekend task... :-)